# Deciding parameters in HoughCircles method of OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect circles in an image, and am using OpenCV Python for the same. I am facing problems when I use the HoughCircles method. I am using the following [custom image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf7Rl.jpg) , but my code is unable to detect both circles.

I tried the following implementation

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(thresh1,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,2,1,param1=100,param2=100,minRadius=0,maxRadius=1000)
```

and this is only properly detecting the bigger circle in the image. I'm pretty sure if I tinker around with the parameters , I might hit upon a combination that works, but is there any way I can calculate, or figure out the parameters, given an image?

**EDIT**

Here is the entire code that I have written:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def show(s , i):
cv2.imshow(s , i)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

img = cv2.imread('ball2.jpg')
show("img" , img)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(cimg,10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
show('thresh' , thresh1)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(thresh1,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,2,1,param1=100,param2=100,minRadius=0,maxRadius=1000)
print circles
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(thresh1,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(100,150,120),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(thresh1,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,0),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',thresh1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Could you post the entire code so that we know exactly where the issue is?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/21/detecting-circles-images-using-opencv-hough-circles/?

Author there suggests to tinker with minDist, as the most important parameter, but you have that set to 1, so rather we should expect false positive than not found circles.
I suggest also to increase param1 to 200 to set upper threshold for the internal Canny edge detector for increased detection.

Also I found some people reported weird anomaly, where increasing maxradius resulted in getting fewer circles. Sometimes it's good idea to leave optional parameters as default (value 0).

From my experience with openCV it often ends up with tinkering parameters to get best results.